# Exchange 2007: export configuration?

Tags: exchange, configuration, exchange-2007

I have to document our Exchange server settings. I dread the prospect of having to export every list and screenshotting every relevant "Properties" window.

Is there a way to just export the (modified) settings to a file?

Comment: Why do you want documentation like this?  This type of documentation will almost certainly become out of sync with the production setup pretty quickly...

Comment: @Zoredache We need documentation because, who remembers which obscure option I had to set some day, hidden behind three layers of mouse clicks? And I want it to be automatically generated for precisely the same reason you mention. If I were to do it manually it'll surely become out of sync; with an automatic tool, I just have to run it to have up-to-date documentation of the current configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2007/11/14/3404361.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Probably yes; let me check tomorrow at work and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Great! Good luck!

Comment: OK, I checked it. The script just nicely formats in XML the output of cmdlets related to CAS, but I still have to rummage in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124413%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) to find the appropriate cmdlets for the rest of the configuration. It's a start, tho.

Comment: Great! Good luck!